# Passing object attribute to method parameter C#

Tags: c#, object, methods

Lets say I have a person class with name and id and a animal class with the same attributes, and i have a list with persons and animals. Now i want to make a method for returning the last id from that list and increment it. I want to make it universal so i can use it later.

```
public static int getNextId(List<Object>param)
{
    int lastId = Int32.Parse(param[param.Count - 1].id);
    if (lastId!=0)
    {
        return lastId++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the 'id' is underlined because object does not have id.

**Edit:**

something like this in python

```
def someMethod(self, someList, attr):
    objAttr = getattr(someObject, attr)
    for(item in someList):
        return item.objAttr
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not how you handle stuff like this in statically typed languages such as C#. You can only access properties / fields that are declared on the specific type. And `object` does not have a public field or property called `id`.

There are some ways around this: One would be having a base class that has an `id` property from which your other classes could inherit:

```
public class IdHolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IdHolder
{
    // Person inherits the 'Id' property from IdHolder
    // other properties unique to person...
}
```

`IdHolder` could just as well be an `interface` or an `abstract class` - it depends on your specific use case (note that you would have to implement the `Id` property in each implementing class if you'd chose to make `IdHolder` an interface).

If you chose to have a base class (or interface, ...) you'd change your method to accept that as a parameter:

```
public static int getNextId(List<IdHolder>param)
{
    int lastId = param[param.Count - 1].Id;
    if (lastId!=0)
    {
        return lastId++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another - slightly dirty - option is to use reflection. As I don't think that this is a sensible route for you to take, I won't go further into this here.

I'd advise you to have a look at an intro book into C# as there are some other aspects of your code that don't really follow C# guidelines (e. g. using camelCase instead of PascalCase).

Comment: Thanks, i think i was confused because in python you can pass a object attribute as a parameter to a method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Person class with a Id Property like this:

```
public class Person
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

So you can use:

```
public static int getNextId(List<Person>param)
{
    int lastId = param.Last().Id;
    if (lastId!=0)
    {
        return lastId++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another aproach is using interfaces to make "universal" like you said:

```
public interface IId
{
     int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Person : IId
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
}

public static int getNextId(List<IId>param)
{
    int lastId = param.Last().Id;
    if (lastId!=0)
    {
        return lastId++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetNextId(List<object> param)
{
    int id = param.OfType<Person>().Last().Id;
    return ++id;
}
```

[OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) method filters the elements based on a specified type. Only people will be filtered from the list of people and animals.

[Last](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a last element of a sequence.